# How to add hidden filed to form with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several divs in my html.

```
<div ng-click="remeber_gift({{gift.id}})">div1</div>
<div ng-click="remeber_gift({{gift.id}})">div2</div>
<div ng-click="remeber_gift({{gift.id}})">div3</div>
```

I want to add hidden filed to clicked div with angular.js and remove all other hidden fields from other divs.

Is this possible at all to do with Angular.js ?
In jquery simple .append is enough.

Comment: I'd use jquery inside your remember_gift function.

Comment: Well ok, but I was just wondering is this possible to do with angular?

Comment: maybe it is, though I don't see the point, since angular is about declarative programming and sharing business logic through a scope. It isn't about DOM manipulation. In fact, AFAIK angular uses jQuery (a stripped down version) for DOM manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to.. but it wouldn't be very clear or succinct Angular code.  You want to avoid DOM manipulation like this as much as you can with Angular.  If you need to have a hidden field with a gift id, you could have just one in your view and ng-bind it to a variable in your scope.

ex `<input type="hidden" ng-bind="saved_gift" />`

Then your `remeber_gift` function could just update that `saved_gift` to the selected `gift.id`.

Comment: Yes I was thinking to use that but I got some funky html where input is ended with </input> with no value. Also previous hidden filed value is not removed but updated with current selection. Any comment?

Comment: What do you mean by the 'previous hidden field value is not removed but updated with current selection.'?

Comment: Sorry, I mean if I have for loop and 40 records then I will have 40 hidden fields. When I do bind then all 40 elements are updated with same value.

Comment: Oh, I see what you want now.  I would use a data structure to make this more simple.  You don't want 40 hidden fields if you can avoid it, right?  A naive solution with 1 hidden field: you  could have comma delimited id's, where "saved_ids" would be something like "9, 6, 267, 2" and then parse them server side.  Or, more elegantly, you could save the values in Angular in an array and then include them into the data you submit the  form.  There are always options, and without code, I can only try to give some valid ones.